# checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) returns true even though my GPS is off

Tags: android, permissions, location

I'm trying to prompt the user to activate GPS if the permission is not granted.
I'm not able to get to the request part because the check is always returning true even when my GPS is turned off.

Here's my code :

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
}
```

I'm expecting the condition to return true since my GPS is off, but instead it is returning false.

Can you please explain to me why i'm getting false for this ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Checking Location permission and asking user to enable GPS is two separate things.

Comment: yes the asking part I couldn't reach it because checking the location permission is returning a positive result all the time no matter what the actual GPS status is.
What is inside the accolades (asking to enable the GPS) is not reached in any case.

Comment: Your GPS can be disabled while your app having the permission. You probably gave the permission. let me attach a code to enable the gps.

Comment: ok i understand better now how this works :) thank you @payam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking user to give your app location permission. To turn on the gps you need another code, so after getting the `true` value do something like this:

```
Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(  
android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);  
startActivity(gpsOptionsIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

`ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission` returns `true` if the user has granted your application the permission to `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`. It has nothing to do with the state of GPS at the device. Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat#checkselfpermission) for more information on how this works.

However, if you want to access or detect the current state of GPS, if it's on or off in the app, you can do this by using this piece of code:

```
if ( (context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager).isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ) 
{
  //gps is on in the device
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Payam said,Enable GPS and Checking location permission are two different things.  You can always  turn on your GPS location from your phone settings.  But for using location api, you have to get permissions in the code.

One more thing, If you phone's android version is 6.0 or higher, then you need to get permissions explicitly by using checkSelfPermissions() method as well as in Manifest file.
But if you have android version lower than 6.0 , then you only need to add permissions in android Manifest.
If my answer helps you then accept my answer by clicking the "Tick mark" symbol on the left side of my answer.